# How to Verify, Allow and Disallow a domain name from accessing a php file via curl

Tags: php, api, curl, dns, verify

I want to be able to verify from where the cURL request comes from.

So, here is the api which the customer will use:

```
$url_api = 'http://apiwebsite.com/api.php';
$post_data = array(
    'test' => 'test',
    'test2' => 'test2',
    'test3' => 'test3',
    );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_api);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
if($output === FALSE){echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($ch);}
curl_close($ch);
print_r($output);
```

And then, on the **apiwebsite.com/api.php** I need to code to verify the origin of the request.

Let's say that **website1.com** requested a code from via curl **apiwebsite.com/api.php**

How can I verify that the domain name is really **website1.com** ? How can I only allow the api access to this particular domain name?

Sending via post or any where else from the customer code is not what I want, because this can be easily breaked/cracked. I want to verify directly from the **apiwebsite.com/api.php** code if the domain requesting the api is really **website1.com**

Is it possible?

If not, can I at least verify the IP Address? Or track anything like nameservers?

Thank you.

PS: Is curl safe to transmit passwords?

Comment: Use htaccess to allow IP address for only website1.com

Answer (score 0):

Use .htaccess to allow the api to only 'website1.com'.  You don't need to check anything in your api file.

use this in your htaccess file

```
   <files api.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 0.0.0.0 (Ip for website1.com)
    allow from 1.1.1.1 (Ip for your server)   
    allow from 1.1.1.1 (Ip for your work/personal/ network)   
    </files>
```

The last two line is to access the `api.php` for yourself.

Comment: Thank you, didn't tought about it.
This code will work perfectly.